# click outside modal close without affecting slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal for a slideshow of photos. I would like for the modal to close when I click outside of the slideshow. My code works but however since the slideshow arrows are inside the modal, when I click on the arrows it closes the modal as well. I would like for the modal to close only when I click on the white space surrounding the image. However the surrounding white space is part of the modal (modal-background) Here is the code:

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(event) {
    // If user either clicks X button OR clicks outside the modal window, then close modal by calling closeModal()
    if (
      event.target.matches(".close") ||
      event.target.closest(".modal")
    ) {
      closeModal()
    }
  },
)

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  // captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
    /* top: 10px; */
    /* left: 25px; */
  right: 365px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
  a.next {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a.previous {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
  }

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <%= image_tag "danica.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(1)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "jess.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(4)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "jimmy.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(7)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "julia.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(10)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "olivia-festival.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(13)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "pete.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(16)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <%= image_tag "santacruz3.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(2)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"  %>
        <%= image_tag "kelly-wet.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(5)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "MorMor.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(8)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "MorMor2.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(11)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "majid.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(14)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "sanfrancisco.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(17)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <%= image_tag "wet.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(3)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "lisbin.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(6)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "santacruz.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(9)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "santacruz2.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(12)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
        <%= image_tag "ny.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(15)", class:"hover-shadow cursor"%>
        <%= image_tag "lipsSF.jpg", style:"width:100%", onclick:"openModal();currentSlide(18)", class:"hover-shadow cursor" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "danica.jpg", style:"width:100%"%>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "jess.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "jimmy.jpg", style:"width:100%"%>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "julia.jpg", style:"width:100%"%>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "olivia-festival.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "pete.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "santacruz3.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "kelly-wet.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "MorMor.jpg", style:"width:100%"%>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "MorMor2.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "majid.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "sanfrancisco.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "wet.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "lisbin.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "santacruz.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "santacruz2.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "ny.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <%= image_tag "lipsSF.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you know the element that you want to target (the white space) simply add that to the `event.target.matches` list rather than `.closest` – `event.target.matches('.theWhiteSpaceElement')`

Comment: Hi There ! If you could replace all the JSP templates  ( <%= image_tag "MorMor2.jpg", style:"width:100%" %>) with static data for now. And edit your question, so that it is displayed on the Web Browser correctly. I will give it a try to resolve this issue for you. I have done this previously at my work place in React. That's why, I thought I used event capturing technique at that time.

Comment: @pilchard this worked! thank you so much !! new to js

Comment: Glad it helped.